# Different variables for multiple link tracking options

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the page loads there are this variables

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"><!--

                /* Conversion Variables */
                s.eVar1="English"
                s.eVar2="sth"
                var s_code=s.t();if(s_code)document.write(s_code)//-->
        </script>
```

I have the following groups of links based on the id.

```
<a href="www.google.com" class="link1")>google</a> <br />
<a href="www.amazon.com" class="link1")>amazon</a> <br />
<a href="www.weather.com" class="link1")>weather</a> <br />

<a href="www.google.com" class="link2")>google</a> <br />
<a href="www.amazon.com" class="link2")>amazon</a> <br />
<a href="www.weather.com" class="link2")>weather</a> <br />
```

I try to make a script in order to manage that if the user click on the link1 id then the variables eVar1 and eVar2 have the default values, on the link2 id then the variables eVar1 and eVar2 change values. How can I make it?

Until now I have this

```
        $(".link1").on('click', 'a', function() { s.tl(this,'e','link', null,'navigate'); return false; });

$(".link2").on('click', 'a', function() { s.tl(this,'e','link', null,'navigate'); return false; });
```

Comment: Statement : Id be unique in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the variables in your click function. And you can use only one click function like the following:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    // save global vars local
    var eVar1 = s.eVar1,
        eVar2 = s.eVar2,
        $a = $(this);

    if ($a.hasClass('link2')) {
        eVar1 = 'Your custom value';
        eVar2 = 'Another custom value';
    }

    $a.click(function(evt) {
        s.eVar1 = eVar1;
        s.eVar2 = eVar2;
        s.linkTrackVars = 'eVar1,eVar2';
        s.tl(this,'e','link', null,'navigate');
        evt.preventDefault();  // is better than return false, isn't it?
    });
});
```

So you can set your custom values.

Comment: very nice solution. However when I test it it doesn't track the link as happened with for example $(".link2").on('click', 'a', function() { s.tl(this,'e','link', null,'navigate'); return false; });

Comment: May you must use `s.linkTrackVars='eVar1,eVar2';` to track this params – I've updated my answer with this info.